# What is the sorting logic behind np.lexsort?

Tags: python, numpy

How does this function work?

```
import numpy as np
first_names = (5,5,5)
last_names = (3,1,2)
x = np.lexsort((first_names, last_names))
print(x)
```

It gives output [1 2 0] . I assume that the two lists are sorted by the variable last_names. If so, how can number 2 have index 0.   2 is between 1 and 3, so I don't understand how this sorting works. please explain.

Answer (score 7):

Essentially, `np.lexsort((first_names, last_names))` says : sort by `last_name` first, then sort by `first_name`

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html), and particularly the example located under "Sort two columns of numbers:", reveals a lot. Essentially, you are first sorting by `last_name`, which reorders that so that index `1` (whose value is 1) is first, index `2` (whose value is 2) is second, and index `0` (whose value is 3) is third. With this order, the sorted `last_name` ends up as `(1,2,3)`, i.e. it is sorted. Then, if there were any ties, the corresponding indices in `first_name` would be the tie breaker.

For example, consider this case:

```
first_names = (5,5,4)
last_names = (3,1,1)
```

There is a tie between index `1` and `2` in `last_name` (they both have the value 1), which will be broken by their corresponding indices in `first_name`. At indices `1` and `2` of `first_name`, index `2` (value 4) is lower than index `1` (value 5), so it will come first. So, the resulting `lexsort` will be `[2,1,0]`:

```
np.lexsort((first_names, last_names))
# array([2, 1, 0])
```

Comment: Take a look at my example one more time please. I deliberately made first_names all the same numbers because I don't want to consider this array at all. So again: last_names = (3,1,2) . and the output is [1, 2, 0] .That proposes that first must go 2, then 3, and then 1 , which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: the output is `[1, 2, 0]` because `last_name` at index `1` is 1, the smallest of the three, at index `2`, it is 2, the second smallest, and at index `0`, it is 3, the biggest of the three.

Answer (score 2):

It returns `[1, 2, 0]` because the index `1` corresponds to '1' in the last name. `2` corresponds to '2' and `0` corresponds to '3'. Think of the return value as the order of indexes you need to use to sort the array:

```
last_names[1], last_names[2], last_names[0] 
# 1, 2, 3
```

sorts the array.

Answer (score 0):

In Layman terms:
Initially, lets sort first_names and last_names separately.

```
first_names = np.array(['Betsey', 'Shelley', 'Lanell', 'Genesis', 'Margery'])
last_names = np.array(['Battle', 'Brien', 'Plotner', 'Stahl', 'Woolum'])
first_names.sort()
first_names
```

> `>>array(['Betsey', 'Genesis', 'Lanell', 'Margery', 'Shelley'], dtype='<U7')`

```
last_names.sort()
last_names
```

> `>>array(['Battle', 'Brien', 'Plotner', 'Stahl', 'Woolum'], dtype='<U7')`

```
[first_names[i] + ' ' + last_names[i] for i in range(len(first_names))]
```

> `>>array(['Betsey Battle', 'Genesis Brien', 'Lanell Plotner', 'Margery Stahl', 'Shelley Woolum'])`

Now lets say we just want to sort names by first_names only

```
first_names = np.array(['Betsey', 'Shelley', 'Lanell', 'Genesis', 'Margery'])
last_names = np.array(['Battle', 'Brien', 'Plotner', 'Stahl', 'Woolum'])
_ = np.lexsort((last_names, first_names))
[first_names[i] + ' ' + last_names[i] for i in _]
```

> `>>['Betsey Battle', 'Genesis Stahl', 'Lanell Plotner', 'Margery Woolum', 'Shelley Brien']`

Here, an obvious question arises:
**What is the significance of np.lexsort() if it is possible to sort with simply array.sort() method?**
If you look carefully at previous 2 outputs, you can find the answer.

For simplicity, Now lets look at another scenario with 2 similar first names.

```
first_names = np.array(['Betsey', 'Shelley', 'Lanell', 'Betsey', 'Margery'])
last_names = np.array(['Battle', 'Brien', 'Plotner', 'Stahl', 'Woolum'])
```

Its not possible to sort first names with corresponding last names with simply sort() method, but lexsort() can sort based on input parameters.

```
_ = np.lexsort((last_names, first_names))
[first_names[i] + ' ' + last_names[i] for i in _]
```

> `>>['Betsey Battle', 'Betsey Stahl', 'Lanell Plotner', 'Margery Woolum', 'Shelley Brien']`

We can do the same thing with multiple arrays like `np.lexsort((last_names, middle_names, first_names))`.
Where arrays will be initially sorted based on `first_names`, if there are similar values then by `middle_names`, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Organizes two lists in pairs, by index -> [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2 ...] in ascending order, in this case, notice the output:

```
# idx:         0   1   2  3  4  5  6
a = np.array ([9, 74, 1, 3, 4, 89, 6])
b = np.array ([4, 6, 9, 2, 1, 8, 7])
```

Out: [2 3 4 6 0 1 5]

The first number is 2, which is the lowest number of a ([]), and will double with 9, since they are of the same index.
To recap, the second smallest number of a ([]) is number 3, which will pair with the 2 of b ([]), since they are of the same index!